# Best approach to open a chat activity after friendlist activity at chat app

Tags: android, android-activity, chat

Let's say I'm making a chat application.

I have an activity `FriendListActivity` (that shows the list of friends)
this activity also has a Socket that listens to every message that comes from the server.

I also have a `ChatActivity` that's called whenever I click at a friend within `FriendListActivity`.

My questions about it:

1. what happens to `FriendListActivity` attributes when I call `ChatActivity` from it? Do they die?
2. How should I place those activities somehow they work together and the atributes don't die?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by 'called whenever I click at a friend within FriendListActivity' you mean that you will create an intent and start the new activity, ChatActivity. If this is what you plan on doing, then the answer to your first question is no - FriendListActivity attributes (and any state information) is maintained in that Activity's class (FriendListActivity). What happens is that ChatActivity now becomes the 'top-level' activity and is presented to the user, while the FriendListActivity will run in the background.

See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html for a good description of how to start new activities and communicate information between them.

Generally, for chat applications, you will create a Thread that handles incoming messages (usually by listening on a socket associated with a server). This thread will block on a socket read operation (the exact function name/API will depend on your particular implementation) and wait for the server to send it data. When data is received on the socket, your thread will put that data into some kind of queue (like an 'unread messages' queue) or call a function in the main application to handle the new message. Keep in mind that the UI can only be updated by your application's main thread, so you'll need a way to exchange information from your Socket to the UI handler in order to say, update a TextView object to display the message to the user.

For the Android-way to communicate information between threads, check out https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html.

If you have any particular examples/code to share that you're having trouble with, update your question and we can try and provide more specific help.